# ^[A-Za-z](\W|\w)* regular expression?

Tags: regex

The regular expression `^[A-Za-z](\W|\w)*` matches when the user gives the first letter as white space, and the first letter should not be a digit and remaining letters may be alpha numerical. When the user gives a white space as the first character it should automatically be trimmed. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^\s*([A-Za-z]\w*)
```

Should do it. Just get group 1.

I'm not sure the language you are using, I'm going to assume C#, so here is a C# sample:

```
string testString = "       myMatch123 not in the match";

Regex regexObj = new Regex("^\\s*([A-Za-z]\\w*)", 
                        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
string result = regexObj.Match(testString).Groups[1].Value;

Console.WriteLine("-" + result + "-");
```

This will print

```
-myMatch123-
```

to the console window.

Comment: hi Ryan Cook it is not triming i tested like " sasi" it is not tring as "sasi" i take a textbox i typed " sasi" and read in a string but it is agin taking " sasi" i need "sasi". is it is possible

Comment: Surya: I updated my post with the exact code needed to get the trimmed result. I ran it and it seems fine. I am thinking that you made a small mistake in the implementation or perhaps I am misunderstanding your request.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to `Trim()` your input before giving it to your regex?

If you're looking for alpha-numerical, starting with non-numeric, you probably want:

```
\s*([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

If you allow one-character user names, change that plus to a star.